# I cannot make my Morea repository private. How do I fix that?

Tags: jekyll, morea-framework

When I try to make my Morea repository private, GitHub says that public forks cannot be made private. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the original QuickStart instructions, which directed you to create a fork of the basic-template.  They have now been fixed, but for those who have already set up a repo, please do the following:

(1) On your laptop, rename your morea directory (let's call it ics314f13/) to ics314f13-old/.   Don't delete the directory, just rename it to something different.

(2) Go to GitHub, and delete your repository (i.e. ics314f13).  You do this in the Settings page.  While this appears scary, don't worry because you still have all your files in your local directory (i.e. ics314f13-old/).  This step will mean that you've lost your commit history, but I assume that's not important. (If history is important, there are other more complicated ways to fix things, let me know.)

(2) Follow the revised QuickStart directions starting here:
http://morea-framework.github.io/quickstart.html#Createacourse

The new instructions direct you to create a new, empty GitHub repo. Use your original repo name, the one you just deleted (i.e. ics314f13).

You'll then download a new script (morea-vanilla-install.sh) and run it to initialize the contents of your empty repo with the contents of basic-template. The net effect is similar to a fork, but since you didn't actually fork, you'll be able to make your repo private if you want.

(3) Copy over the changed files from your "old" directory to your "new" directory.

You'll typically just copy over the file master/src/_config.yml and the entire directory master/src/morea/.

Advanced users like Cam might have created new navbar pages.   He'll need to copy over these changes as well.

(4) Copy over scripts.

Copy over the morea-run-local.sh script from the "old" directory, and check to make sure everything looks OK.

Copy over the morea-publish.sh script from the "old" directory, and run it to push your changes to your new GitHub repo.

(5) Make your repo private.

You should now be able to go to the settings menu and make your repo private.